# How to find connecting flights within 1 table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression

I am practicing SQL and I have a table called `flights` that has the flight `id`, `origin`, `destination`, and the `cost` of the trip. I want to be able to find all the cheapest possible flights that can be done in two or fewer stops, while also displaying how many stops each flight has along with the total cost of the flight. Also, if two trips cost the same, then I want the one with the fewest stops.

Here is the table on db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mvvE24KAxnayR9fRmHChMw/1

This is what I have so far and it is not completed since I am missing the number of stops and some flights. I am unsure how to count the number of stops between flights or how to get all flights that are connecting.

I feel like this could be done without a recursive CTE, but I am unsure. I also feel like my query is very messy. Any help would be useful!

Thanks!

Query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE connecting_flights AS (

  SELECT origin, destination, cost 
  FROM flights

  UNION ALL

  SELECT f.origin, f.destination, cf.cost
  FROM flights f
  INNER JOIN connecting_flights cf ON cf.origin = f.destination

), flight_data as (
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT flights.origin as original_flight
       , flights.destination as original_destination
       , flights.cost as flights_cost
       , cf.origin as cf_origin
       , cf.destination as cf_destination
       ,cf.cost as cf_cost
       , flights.cost + cf.cost as total_cost
    FROM flights
    LEFT JOIN connecting_flights cf ON cf.origin = flights.destination
    LEFT JOIN flights b ON b.origin = cf.origin
) 

SELECT
    original_flight
    , CASE 
        WHEN cf_destination IS NULL THEN original_destination
        ELSE cf_destination
     END as destination
   , CASE
       WHEN cf_destination IS NULL THEN flights_cost
       ELSE total_cost
    END as total
FROM flight_data
ORDER BY original_flight
```

Comment: Are those flights between concrete two cities or any of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a way of doing using the recursive cte option. Here you can choose the root and the destination and find out the ones which take the least stops and the least money

```
   with recursive cte
     as(select origin,destination,cast(destination as varchar(1000)) as str_path,origin as root,cost,0 as lvl 
         from flights
       union all
       select ua.origin,ua.destination,cast(concat(str_path,'-',ua.destination) as varchar(1000)),c.root,c.cost+ua.cost,c.lvl+1
         from cte c
         join flights ua
           on c.destination=ua.origin
          and c.str_path not like concat('%',ua.destination,'%')  
         )
  select * from cte  order by 4,2,cost asc 

+--------+-------------+-------------+------+------+-----+
| origin | destination |  str_path   | root | cost | lvl |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------+------+-----+
| DFW    | JFK         | JFK         | DFW  |  200 |   0 |
| JFK    | LHR         | JFK-LHR     | DFW  | 1200 |   1 |
| DFW    | MCO         | MCO         | DFW  |  100 |   0 |
| JFK    | LHR         | LHR         | JFK  | 1000 |   0 |
| SFO    | DFW         | DFW         | SFO  |  200 |   0 |
| DFW    | JFK         | DFW-JFK     | SFO  |  400 |   1 |
| SFO    | JFK         | JFK         | SFO  |  500 |   0 |
| JFK    | LHR         | DFW-JFK-LHR | SFO  | 1400 |   2 |
| JFK    | LHR         | JFK-LHR     | SFO  | 1500 |   1 |
| DFW    | MCO         | DFW-MCO     | SFO  |  300 |   1 |
| SFO    | MCO         | MCO         | SFO  |  400 |   0 |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------+------+-----+
```

db fiddle link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2fc63555177972cb6c60e63d030fc9af

Comment: Is there any way this solution would be able to accept an origin and destination, ive tried several variations but cant find anything that works out. The reason being I need to get these results in quick fire requests and not a large single process

Comment: the column str_path may be used to search for origin ie (where str_path like 'ORIG%' and str_path like '%DEST') AND <add_other_conditions>

Answer (score 2):

Since you only consider up to two steps, you can use `union all`:

```
select f.origin, f.destination, 0 steps, f.cost, f.origin || '->' || f.destination route
from flights f
union all
select f1.origin, f2.destination, 1, f1.cost + f2.cost, f1.origin || '->' || f1.destination || '->' || f2.destination route
from flights f1
inner join flights f2 on f1.destination = f2.origin
union all
select f1.origin, f3.destination, 2, f1.cost + f2.cost + f3.cost, f1.origin || '->' || f1.destination || '->' || f2.destination || '->' || f3.destination route
from flights f1
inner join flights f2 on f1.destination = f2.origin
inner join flights f3 on f2.destination = f3.origin
order by cost, steps
```

Result:

```
| origin | destination | steps | cost | route              |
| ------ | ----------- | ----- | ---- | ------------------ |
| DFW    | MCO         | 0     | 100  | DFW->MCO           |
| SFO    | DFW         | 0     | 200  | SFO->DFW           |
| DFW    | JFK         | 0     | 200  | DFW->JFK           |
| SFO    | MCO         | 1     | 300  | SFO->DFW->MCO      |
| SFO    | MCO         | 0     | 400  | SFO->MCO           |
| SFO    | JFK         | 1     | 400  | SFO->DFW->JFK      |
| SFO    | JFK         | 0     | 500  | SFO->JFK           |
| JFK    | LHR         | 0     | 1000 | JFK->LHR           |
| DFW    | LHR         | 1     | 1200 | DFW->JFK->LHR      |
| SFO    | LHR         | 2     | 1400 | SFO->DFW->JFK->LHR |
| SFO    | LHR         | 1     | 1500 | SFO->JFK->LHR      |
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was looking more of something like DWF -> MCO has 0 stops and it costs $100. SFO to LHR would have 2 stops and cost $1400 since going from SFO -> DFW -> JFK -> LHR would be cheaper than going from SFO -> JFK -> LHR. The origin and destination should not be considered a stop, only the flights between them.

Comment: @DNg is this really an issue? Additional select needs to be added. I have changed the answer

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this myself, both George and Andronicus gave me ideas on how to solve the problem.

In the end, I wanted to produce a list of flights that only display the cheapest flights excluding the flights that are more expensive.

```
WITH RECURSIVE connecting_flights AS (

  SELECT origin, destination, cost, 0 AS stops
  FROM flights

  UNION ALL

  SELECT cf.origin, f.destination, (cf.cost + f.cost) as cost, cf.stops + 1 AS stops
  FROM flights f
  INNER JOIN connecting_flights cf ON cf.destination = f.origin
  WHERE cf.stops <= 2 and cf.origin <> f.destination
  )

SELECT flights.origin, flights.destination, cf.stops, MIN(flights.cost) as total_cost
FROM connecting_flights AS flights
INNER JOIN connecting_flights AS cf ON cf.origin = flights.origin 
   AND cf.destination = flights.destination
GROUP BY flights.origin, flights.destination, cf.stops, cf.cost
HAVING MIN(flights.cost) = cf.cost
ORDER BY origin, destination;
```